# How can I add homescreen shortcut for app after installing

Tags: java, android, shortcut

How can I add shortcut of my application to Android homescreen before I lauch app?

I need it added right after installation of app.

Comment: Your app should already be added to the "app drawer". Not all launchers have a "home screen"

Comment: Don't, it's obnoxious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you publish your app in google play store after installing app auto-create shortcut but if you want to handle that Android provides us an intent class com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT which can be used to add shortcuts to the home screen. In following code snippet we create a shortcut of activity MainActivity with the name HelloWorldShortcut.

First, we need to add permission INSTALL_SHORTCUT to android manifest XML.

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

The addShortcut() method creates a new shortcut on the Home screen.

```
private void addShortcut() {
    //Adding shortcut for MainActivity 
    //on Home screen
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);

    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "HelloWorldShortcut");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.ic_launcher));

    addIntent
            .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);  //may it's already there so don't duplicate
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

Note how we create shortcut Intent object which holds our target activity. This intent object is added into another intent as EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT.

Finally, we broadcast the new intent. This adds a shortcut with the name mentioned as EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME and icon defined by EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE.

Also put this code to avoid multiple shortcuts :

```
  if(!getSharedPreferences(Utils.APP_PREFERENCE, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(Utils.IS_ICON_CREATED, false)){
          addShortcut();
          getSharedPreferences(Utils.APP_PREFERENCE, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(Utils.IS_ICON_CREATED, true);
      }
```

Comment: But this code will add shortcut only after I run app. But how can I start my app without a shortcut? After installing I can't find it on app list. I can find it only in Settings->Apps. And there is no "Run" button.

Comment: it's possible just the app installed from stores not install directly